# My page is not stretching across the entire page

Tags: html, css

I have two questions. The first is that when I write in my html tag I cannot use my the hyperlink when running the page. The other and main reason is that my code will not stretch across the entire page.

[image: What my code outputs]

Here is the css I wrote for styling the page

```
body {
    background: #B2906F;
    font-family: arial;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.maincontainer{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.picture{
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.button{
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #05280c;
}
.button-primary:hover {
    background-color: #05370c;
}

h1  {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #2c421f;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}

ul{
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 250px;
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    color: #050c0c;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

ul li a {
    color: black;
}

footer{
    clear: both;
}

nav {
    color: 
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #2c421f;
}
```

and this is my html I wrote for the page. Any help would be awesome. I have been stuck here for a couple days.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>NWWolfPack</title>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="maincontainer">
        <h1>NW Wolf Pack</h1>
        <div class="picture"><img src="camo.jpg" width="100%" height="150">
            <header>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="button"><strong>Home</strong></li>
                        <li><a href="records.html" class="button button-primary"><strong>Records</strong></a></li>
                        <li><a href="membership.html" class="button button-primary"><strong>Membership</strong></a></li>
                        <li><a href="contactus.html" class="button button-primary"><strong>Contact Us</strong></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </div>
        <footer>2017 Dillan Hall</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What was the question again...? :|

Comment: Sorry i worded that awfully. I just want my css to run across the page from left to right. At the moment it only goes half way

Comment: check your begin and end div tags in your code. I don't think you were intending to have that header nav inside the picture div.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this:

```css
body {
  background: #B2906F;
  font-family: arial;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.maincontainer {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.picture {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.button {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #05280c;
}

.button-primary:hover {
  background-color: #05370c;
}

h1 {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #2c421f;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 250px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  color: #050c0c;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

ul li a {
  color: black;
}

footer {
  clear: both;
}

nav {
  color: height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #2c421f;
}
```

```html
<div class="maincontainer">
        <h1>NW Wolf Pack</h1>
        <div class="picture"><img src="camo.jpg" width="100%" height="150">
            <header>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="button"><strong>Home</strong></li>
                        <li><a href="records.html" class="button button-primary"><strong>Records</strong></a></li>
                        <li><a href="membership.html" class="button button-primary"><strong>Membership</strong></a></li>
                        <li><a href="contactus.html" class="button button-primary"><strong>Contact Us</strong></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </div>
        <footer>2017 Dillan Hall</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the `position:fixed` on the .picture in your css that is causing your issue. Also I just noticed that your maincontainer does not have the closing div.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position:fixed` from your class `picture`

```
.picture{
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    z-index: -1;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

And your hyperlink seems to be working..Isnt that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>NWWolfPack</title>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" />



</head>

<body>
    <div class="maincontainer">
        <h1>NW Wolf Pack</h1>
        <div class="picture"><img src="http://www.dvd-ppt-slideshow.com/images/ppt-background/background-5.jpg" width="100%" height="150">
            <header>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="button"><strong>Home</strong></li>
                        <li><a href="records.html" class="button button-primary"><strong>Records</strong></a></li>
                        <li><a href="membership.html" class="button button-primary"><strong>Membership</strong></a></li>
                        <li><a href="contactus.html" class="button button-primary"><strong>Contact Us</strong></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </div>
        <footer>2017 Dillan Hall</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

STYLE:

```
<style>
    button{
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #05280c;
}
.button-primary:hover {
    background-color: #05370c;
}

h1  {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #2c421f;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}

ul{
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 250px;
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    color: #050c0c;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

ul li a {
    color: black;
}

footer{
    clear: both;
}

nav {
    color: 
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #2c421f;
}
    </style>
```

Hope this will help you. If any other question let me know?